# javascript - intersect prototype with global variable

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
var Song = function(side, name, index, duration, author, lyrics) {
    this.side = side;
    this.name = name;
    this.index = index;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.author = author;
    this.lyrics = lyrics;
    globalLyrics.push(this.lyrics);
 };
```

with instances such as:

```
    var song1 = new Song('Mithras', 'Wicked', 1, '3:45', 'Me and The Plant', 
           ["politicians", "politician", "politics", "telling", 
           "lies", "lie", "to", "media", "the", "youngsters", 
           "young", "elders", "time", "that", "passes", "pass", "by", 
           "oh", "no", "lie", "detector", "detection", "souls", "as", 
           "far", "illusion", "goes", "all", "sinners", "sin", "around", 
           "sun", "earth", "atom", "atoms", "mind", "angels", "angel", 
           "prophet", "prophets", "martyr", "knives", "elder", "detect", 
           "shit", "flies", "fly", "meat", "is", "knife", "and", "death", 
           "life", "I", "am", "gonna", "going", "cast", "a", "sacred", 
           "circle"]);
```

given an input that is a global variable:

```
    var input = ["politician", "going", "cast"];
```

and a countIntersection function:

```
   function countIntersect(input, lyrics) {

       var temp = [];
       for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
           for(var k = 0; k < lyrics.length; k++){
              if(input[i] == lyrics[k]){
                  temp.push(input[i]);
                  break;
               }
           }
        }
        return temp.length;   
     }
```

QUESTION:

I don't want to make `input` part of song `prototype`.

how do I adjust this `countIntersection` `function` so that `global` `input` intersects with `this.lyrics`?

Comment: What output are you getting? What is the desired output? What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either make `countIntersection` a method on your `Song` object, or pass your `Song` instance into the function (instead of just the lyrics).

For example:

```
var Song = function () {...}
Song.prototype.countIntersect = function (input) {
   var lyrics = this.lyrics;
   var count = 0;

   for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
       for(var k = 0; k < lyrics.length; k++){
          if(input[i] == lyrics[k]){
              count += 1;
           }
       }
    }

    return count;  
 }
```

then

```
var song1 = new Song(...);

song1.countIntersect(input); // 21
```